# Stokes' Theorem in a cylinder

Tags: line-integrals, stokes-theorem, curl

I have to use the Stokes' Theorem to evaluate the exterior flow of the vectorial field
$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(xy^{2},x^{2}y,y)$$
throught the border of the solid bounded by the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$ and the planes $z=1$ and $z=-1$.

My question is: Stokes use curl. So should I find a vectorial field $G$ such that
$$curl G=F$$
and then apply Stokes on it?

And since Stokes use line integral, what is the curve $\gamma$ that I'm supposed to use? I thought that
$$\gamma=\gamma_{1}\cup\gamma_{2}\cup\gamma_{3}\cup\gamma_{4}$$
where $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ are the curves described by the bases of the cylinder ($x^{2}+y^{2}=1$) and $\gamma_{3}$ like $\gamma_{4}$ are the curves given by the height of the cylinder, ie, from $z=-1$ to $z=1$, but I'm really not sure about it.

Comment: Your surface has no boundary, how can you apply Stokes's Theorem?

Comment: Do you mean Divergence Theorem?

Comment: Actually, I thought that too haha but it's a question from a test, so I thought I was wrong. I couldn't see no boundary at all to apply the theorem.

Comment: Maybe it's wrong then, cause in the test it says to use Stokes.

Comment: But divergence is the best one to evaluate it.

Comment: In more advanced mathematics, Stokes's Theorem includes all of them: Green's, Stokes's, Gauss's (Divergence) in the plane and 3-space. Yes, this is an immediate application of the divergence theorem. Besides, there is no $\vec G$, since $\text{div}\,\vec F \ne 0$.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is equation for a circle. I will edit your question for clarity.

Comment: @unseen_rider: first, $x^2+y^2=1$ is indeed the equation of a cylinder (in the right context, of course, which is the case here). Second, as you wrote it the description makes no sense: a circle and two planes do not bound a solid.

Comment: The border is $\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2$.

Comment: Is the "exterior flow" the flux of the field on that surface? I'm unfamiliar with the term

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C$ be the described cylinder.

I'm going to assume by "exterior flow" you mean the integral:

$$\int_{\partial C}\mathbf F \cdot \hat{\mathbf n} \, \mathrm dS$$

By the divergence theorem form of Stokes's Theorem, this is equal to:

$$\int_C \nabla\cdot\mathbf F \, \mathrm dV$$

$$=\int_C(y^2 + x^2+0)\, \mathrm dV$$

As $C$ is a cylinder, you should convert to cylindrical coordinates.